# devise 3.4.1 with multiple usernames and reset password forbiddenAttributesError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have multiple possible user names in my user model i.e. a user can login with either one.
This is based on the article here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address

The actual login is working fine with either code, but following the example I cannot get the reset password page to fire properly.

This is a multi-tenant scenario so there is also an account_id to take into consideration.
I have found many other people with the same issue - but I don't know what the right way to resolve this is, if I permit! in the relevant method (below) then reset password functions but standard login no longer works.

I am getting a ForbiddenAttributesError as follows:

```
  ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError - ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError:
  activemodel (4.1.6) lib/active_model/forbidden_attributes_protection.rb:21:in `sanitize_for_mass_assignment'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:568:in `where!'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:559:in `where'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/querying.rb:10:in `where'
  app/models/user.rb:356:in `find_first_by_auth_conditions'
  devise (3.4.1) lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb:266:in `find_or_initialize_with_errors'
  devise (3.4.1) lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb:115:in `send_reset_password_instructions'
  devise (3.4.1) app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb:13:in `create'
```

User.rb

```
 devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, authentication_keys: [:login, :account_id], reset_password_keys: [:login, :account_id]

....

  def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)

    # IF i switch these 2 lines then reset password works BUT normal login doesn't
    #conditions = warden_conditions.dup.permit!
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup

    if login = conditions.delete(:login)
      where(conditions).where(["lower(remote_id) = :value OR lower(other_id) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
    else
      where(conditions).first
    end
  end
```

application_controller.rb

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

...

def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:remote_id, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me) }
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:login, :remote_id, :email, :password, :remember_me) }
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:remote_id, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
end
```

Using devise 3.4.1, rails 4.1.6